# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given for join query

Tags: php, laravel, join

I have a column named user_id in avtivities table. Now i want to fetch the names of user whose user_id stored in activities_table. So far i tried this

```
$activity_user=DB::table('users')
                ->join('activities','users.id','activities.user_id')
                ->select('users.name')->first();
```

but when i try to call it on view like this

```
<td style="text-align: center">{{ $activity->user_id ? $activity_user : ""}}</td>
```

i got this error

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\task-management-system\resources\views\super_admin\home.blade.php)
```

[image]

Comment: what value of the user object are you wanting to be printed?

Comment: actually i have table called activities and in this table i want to show the user name, his login time and logout time

Comment: what value do you want to be showing in your blade example above?

Comment: i want to show the user names from user table

Comment: your query is only for 1 record, `first()`

Comment: yest first i use get() but when i a use this i got result like array can you please see the image i edited my answer.

Comment: yes you're getting multiple arrays using `get()`. In `first()` method you get only one object. So if you want to show your names in `td` tag you need to run `loop`  Check I show you in my answer how to show it.

Comment: Try this {{ $activity_user->name }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ $activity->user_id ? $activity_user : ""}}
```

In this `$activity_user` is object and you're showing object, So instead use `$activity_user` use this `$activity_user->name` now your code looks like,

```
{{ $activity_user ? $activity_user->name : ""}}
```

**Note:** Make sure whatever you print in `{{ }}` should be string.

### Update

If you want to get multiple data then.

```
$activity_user=DB::table('users')
                ->join('activities','users.id','activities.user_id')
                ->select('users.name')->get();
```

**View file**

```
<td style="text-align: center">
@if(!empty($activity_user))
    @foreach($activity_user as $user)
        {{ $user ? $user->name : ""}}
    @endforeach
@endif


</td>
```

Comment: yes error is go now according to your answer but it always give me the first user name whose id is 1. But in my activity table there is 2 user_id respectively 1 and 2

Comment: It just becuase you're fetching `first()` object. Use `get` instead `first()`